# What's the word for moving a stroller back and forth to sooth the baby?

Tags: word-request

When a mom or dad need to sooth their baby they move a stroller back and forth. What's the verb for moving a stroller back and forth to sooth the baby?

Comment: The default word for gentle / repetitive movement intended to lull a baby to sleep is ***rocking***. See [Rock-a-bye Baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-a-bye_Baby)

Comment: FFRMonica, that seems a perfectly good answer to the question posed. Why did you post it as a comment, rather than as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The default word for gentle / repetitive movement intended to lull a baby to sleep is **rocking**. See [Rock-a-bye Baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-a-bye_Baby) – FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica